# using mod_rewrite to create unique user address

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use the mod_rewrite function to allow my users to create their own unique url's.

Currently, users can access their public profiles by visiting www.mywebsite.com/user/index/4588
where `4588` is that users `id` number in the database.

I have read up on mod_rewrite here: http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/
but I don't know how to test it out.

Someone advised me that the script I am using already uses mod_rewrite to get the users `id` number for the url, so how can I change it?

Even if to start I could get rid of the `/user/index/` part from the url that would be a start.

This is the current .htaccess file in my root which presumably does the current mod_rewrite for public profiles:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Can somebody advise me what to do next in order to start changing it from id's to usernames?
Both are unique within the db.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your htaccess file seems like you are using one of the php mvc framework (Zend?). If this is a case then you don't need to play with mod_rewrite but configure your framework router.

Have a look at 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html